# Reconnect Milo Client

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I want the Client to reconnect to the Server if the server went down and up again. I can add an SessionActivityListener to the Client which gets notified on SessionInactive and the SessionActive if the Server is back online. However, when i get the SessionActive and try to resubscribe i get an "secure channel invalid" error message.

> 14:32:28.209 [ua-netty-event-loop-11] ERROR o.e.m.o.s.c.h.UaTcpClientAcknowledgeHandler - [remote=/127.0.0.1:53530] Received error message: ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecureChannelIdInvalid, value=0x80220000, quality=bad}, reason=Bad_SecureChannelIdInvalid (code=0x80220000, description="The specified secure channel is no longer valid.")}

so what i'm currently doing is, disconnect the client and create a completely new client with the same subscriptions as the old client. but i guess thats pretty hacky. so the question is, is there a way to just update the "old" clients connection and subscriptions?

i'm currently testing with the prosys simulation server

greetings,
Lukas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the client has successfully connected it will automatically reconnect any time the connection is broken. It will attempt to resume the old session or create a new session automatically if necessary, and try to transfer subscriptions if a new session was created. This is all handled for you.

Subscription transfer may fail or not be supported by the server, in which case you need to re-create the subscriptions yourself. You should add a `SubscriptionListener` to the `OpcUaSubscriptionManager` and implement the `onSubscriptionTransferFailed` callback, which notifies you that transfer failed and you need to re-create this subscription yourself.